# Status bar background changed after ads dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, admob, uinavigationbar

The view structure is: TabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController. The view shows AdMob interstitial ads.

Before the ads shows, it looks normal like this

[image]

After ads shows and dismissed, it looks like this

[image]

There is nothing to do when ads dismissed

```
   func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

    }
```

I had tried to refresh the status bar and navigation bar, not work.

BTW, this will not happen on iPhone X, Xs, Xr, Xs Max. The status bar return normal after press another tab bar item. I finally found that it seems no such problem on real device.

Comment: show the code, how it gets dismissed??

Comment: @McDonal_11 No any code in `interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial)`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Comment: When user dismiss ads `interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial)` will be called. Where should I put code in?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I found this problem happens on simulator iPhone 5,6,7,8. There is no such problem on a real device. :-(